# unexpected token on accept json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json external api i'm calling. However the response is coming back as json, and if i dont have the datatype as jsonp, The api fails with an access control issue.

I can hit the api fine with postman. And receive the response fine. However in the console i get `unexpected token ':'`

Heres my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  },
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: 'URL' + somevarhere,
  success: function(json) {
    debugger
    for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
      var section = json.results[i].name;
      var tid = json.results[i].Id.slice(1);
      var price = json.results[i].minPrice;
      var url = json.results[i].url;
      var button =
        "<a class='btn btn-info'>Buy Now</a>";
      $("#tableid").append("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/logo.png'/></td><td><b>" + section +
        "</b></td><td><b> In Stock </b></td><td><b>£" + price + "</b></td><td><b>N/A</b></td><td><b>£" + price + "</b></td><td><b>" + button + "</b></td></tr>");
      $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
        location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
      });
    }
    sortTable();
  },
  error: function(error) {
    debugger
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

If i swap the datatype i get `no access origin` error

Any Ideas?

Ok in postman i get this response

```
{"details":{"totalResults":3,"totalPages":1,"currentPage":1,"resultsPerPage":50},"results":[{"eventId":2148477, So on so forth
```

Sam

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a jsfiddle? (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: cant get passed the http https error in on the api link.

Comment: Can you show the api url?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Its a private URL, I can add the some of the response

Comment: Your json response is not valid. Check in this link: http://pro.jsonlint.com/.

Comment: How can i get the response to be valid? Can i convert it as i receive it or?

Comment: The proper way should be correcting from the server. Can you do that?

Comment: I dont have access to the server at all, Its a professional company that hosts the api

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez , I added the url to the pro.jsonlint.com and i got a tick on the right  in a green box, Guessing it means its okay?

Comment: Can you update your question with the full `json` response? BTW, there is no `jsonp` in your response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100524/discussion-between-sam-roberts-and-danny-fardy-jhonston-bermudez).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual response contains `json` and not `jsonp`.

With your current URL (`'URL' + somevarhere`), you have cors issues. However you can use the (https://crossorigin.me/) service to avoid this issue.

Then, you should request: «https://crossorigin.me/(`'URL' + somevarhere`)».

Try using this service.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving JSONP from the API then your content type should be javascript, not json.

[Check out this for reference.](http://blog.tompawlak.org/json-jsonp-correct-mime-type)

So

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

should be

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/javascript");
```

Let me know if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSONP response is not valid. The JSON should be wrapped in a callback with a name from `callback` request parameter, for example:

```
callback({a: 1, b: 2});
```

Comment: And can i do this within the ajax?

Comment: @SamRoberts Your JavaScript code is good, you have to modify code that generates JSONP response. If you can't modify the API's code I'm afraid you can't fetch it with AJAX due to Same-Origin Policy.